# Riemann Integrable Functions Sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I cannot use the definition of limsup for this problem so I'm kind of stuck.

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, let $f(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in [a,b]$, and let $M_n := \left(\int_a^b f^n\right)^{1/n}$. Show that $\mathrm{lim}(M_n)=\mathrm{sup}\{f(X): x\in [a,b]\}$.

My attempt: I thought about using the maximum minimum theorem and squeezing it between two functions but it didn't work.

Since $f$ is continuous there are elements $x^*, x_* \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_*)\leq f \leq f(x^*)$. Then $f(x_*)^n(b-a)\leq \int_a^b f^n \leq f(x^*)^n(b-a)$ or $f(x_*)(b-a)^{1/n}\leq \left(\int_a^b f^n\right)^{1/n} \leq f(x^*)(b-a)^{1/n}$. This is where I'm stuck. Should I try a different approach? Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Consider only a short interval $[c,d]$ about $x^\ast$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can assume without loss of generality that $f(x^*)=1$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f(x^*)=1$, there exists $\delta>0$ with $\delta<1/2$ and $f(x)>1-\frac\varepsilon2$ on $(x^*-\delta,x^*+\delta)$. Then
$$
\left(\int_a^bf^n\right)^{1/n}\geq \left(\int_{x^*-\delta}^{x^*+\delta}f^n\right)^{1/n}\geq(1-\frac\varepsilon2)(2\delta)^{1/n}
$$

As you say, now using $\limsup$ would be very useful. But we can do it this way: fix $n_0$ such that $(2\delta)^{1/n}>1-\varepsilon/2$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Then, for all $n\geq n_0$,
$$
\left|1-\left(\int_a^bf^n\right)^{1/n}\right|=1-\left(\int_a^bf^n\right)^{1/n}\\\leq1-(1-\frac\varepsilon2)(2\delta)^{1/n}=1-(2\delta)^{1/n}+\frac\varepsilon2(2\delta)^{1/n}<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon
$$